# SQL database cpu 100%utilization

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

sql server cpu utilization is high how to fix what and alll needd to check  should I check the

Please let me what do how to fix the issues
All maintance job are running fine

Answer (score 0):

It could be that there's some other program entirely running on the server chewing up the CPU, so I'd suggest opening task manager or resource monitor first, just to check whether SQL Server *itself* is using all that CPU. Because that would be unusual.

After you've done that, if you see that it really is SQL using all the CPU, a quick way of getting at least some information, which might let you see if the CPU is being consumed by user queries or system processes, is to execute the procedure `sp_who2`. This will return a table of values indicating the session id, login name, host name (the machine the client is connecting from), and so on, as well as a column for CPUTime. Run that, have a look at any of the rows with high CPUTime values.

Note, however, that there are system processes that run for a very long time and will seem to have very high CPU time, because they're "always running" so to speak.

If you want to get more detailed information, you could create Adam Machanic's excellent `sp_whoisactive` stored procedure on your instance, and run that. You can download the DDL, and read the documentation about it, [here](http://whoisactive.com/downloads/)